# export to csv from more than 1 tabel

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with export data from mysql to .csv file belongs to customer id.
When I'm trying to export i have errors with header and query.
 When I paste the query into the mysql i receiving the values but it duplicate entries.
Anyone have idea how to solve that without any additional libraries?

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT A.user_name, B.mr_name, C.mpl_name FROM t_user A
INNER JOIN t_mr_pom B ON A.id = B.t_user_id
INNER JOIN t_mpl_pom C ON A.id = C.t_user_id
WHERE A.id LIKE $id GROUP BY B.id";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$filename = "exported-" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

$file = fopen($filename, "w");
$delimeter = ",";
$headers = array('Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3');
fputcsv($file, $headers, $delimeter);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data = array($row['user_name'], $row['mr_name'], $row['mpl_name']);
    fputcsv($file, $data, $delimeter);
}

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($filename);

unlink($filename);
exit();
```

Comment: Do you have problem with headers of CSV, headers of request or mysql query? Can you provide some examples what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/html/test/export.php on line 17 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/test/export.php:17) in /var/www/html/test/export.php on line 22 / 23 / 24/ 25

Comment: Your query is incorrect. Check in DB whether it returns correct output.

Comment: Strange, when i remove from query "Group by" it shows result with duplicate values from other tabel. In t_mr_pom i have 3 values in t_mpl_pom have 1 value, when i execute query it shows 3 values from t_mr_pom (correct) and 3  same values from t_mpl_pom (incorrect - should show only 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE A.id LIKE $id GROUP BY B.id
```

Do not use `LIKE` here. Use `=`. If `$id` is `1`, the results will be duplicated for each ID which contains `1`: `10`, `11`, `12`,...

Comment: So the query should looks like: SELECT DISTINCT A.user_name, B.mr_name, C.mpl_name FROM t_user A
INNER JOIN t_mr_pom B ON A.id = B.t_user_id
INNER JOIN t_mpl_pom C ON A.id = C.t_user_id
WHERE A.id = $id GROUP BY B.id